filter lines in loki by selected time tange
In Grafana / Loki I am evaluating log files (x.log, x.log.1 , ..).
I am doing
{host="my_host, job="varlogs", filename=~"/var/log/x.log.*"} |= `SIGTERM`

This will display all logs independent from the selected time range.
I know that with e.g. ${__from:date:iso} I can access the values from the selected time range and I have already used this for SQL queries. How can I use it in Loki like
| (${__from:datetime:iso} < line < ${__to:datetime:iso} 

? Or do I need to use a transformation?
(Unfortunately the application is still using log files instead of jornald...)
